# wordpress shortcode not working in php files?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

hello friends i am working with wordpress framework.

i know about the shortcode the wordpress shortcode is very beauty full concept.

but i face something wrong in the [Cool Video Gallery](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cool-video-gallery/)

this plugin is allow to write a shortcode in the posts and page.

after you create video gallery this plugin is generate the shortcode then you past that shortcode in posts and page.

i write that shortcode in php file like this.

```
echo do_shortcode("[cvg-video videoId='2' width='600' height='600' mode='playlist' /]");
```

this is not return any thing.

but i write this shortcode in posts and page that return a videos.

then after i will try to fond where register this shortcode.

generally wordpress shortcode is working when you register shortcode using this function.

```
add_shortcode('shortcodename','functionwritecode');
```

ok so i will try find where register this shortcode in plugin coll video gallery.

but i can't find where register this shortcode.

please if any one used this plugin and find the where register this shortcode please tell about this.

so i want to know how to work [Coll video Gallery](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cool-video-gallery/)

and how to write that like shortcode.

this shortcode is working on the posts and page in wordpress.

also you can't use this shortcode in any php file.

because you write this shorcode in php file like this.

```
echo do_shortcode("[cvg-video videoId='2' width='600' height='600' mode='playlist' /]");
```

there is nothing return any things.

i am writeing this short code in posts the return videos.

so i want to know how to write this type of shortcode.

thank you.

Comment: have you echo'd it out? it should be echo do_shortcode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong quote/apostrophe used right at beginning and end:

```
do_shortcode('[cvg-video videoId='2' width='600' height='600' mode='playlist' /]');
```

should read

```
echo do_shortcode("[cvg-video videoId='2' width='600' height='600' mode='playlist' /]");
```

Comment: Ok what is being returned?

Comment: Can you post the actual function?

Comment: ok dear i used the cool video gallery plugin i don't know which function is used this plugin. this short code i write i have only this short code.